# How to start two instances of play application?

Tags: java, web-applications, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to deploy two instances of same play application in different ports and load balance between then through nginx in front.

As per the [manual](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/HTTPServer), to start multiple instances of play, these are the commands.

```
$ start -Dhttp.port=9998
$ start -Dhttp.port=9999
```

But, if I gave those, the first command properly starts my application in port 9998, but the second commands fails to do so by giving following message.

```
This application is already running (Or delete /play/app/folder/RUNNING_PID file)
```

I'm using Ubuntu 12.05.

So, how can I start multiple instances of single play instance?

Comment: It seems like your play application checks its running status by creating a dummy file on `/play/app/folder/RUNNING_PID`. You might want to change the program to not check its running status using this file so that multiple processes can run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ start -Dhttp.port=9998 -Dpidfile.path=/path/to/app1/pidfile
$ start -Dhttp.port=9999 -Dpidfile.path=/path/to/app2/pidfile
```

Just make sure the two pidfile paths that you pass to each app are different.

This is documented here:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ProductionConfiguration

Comment: What's when you need to update the content of the folder (svn update), make "clean" or some other stuff? Both instances will need to be stopped before that?
I guess in that case would be better to have two folders with the same play application and run it in both?