# How to run 2 different play! framework instances on the same local machine in 2 different ports?

Tags: java, playframework

I want to run a user management service as a play instance and a whole another application as another play instance. I want both of these play instances to run on the same machine and on 2 different ports.

Comment: Sorry, I flagged this as a duplicate of the wrong ticket. Should be marked as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/22445710 which explains how to change the port and pid file.

Comment: `sbt "run {port-number}"` will work if there's nothing already listening on that port.

Answer (score 2):

You could use SBT to run an instance of an application on a specific port:

```
$your-app-folder/ sbt "run 10000"
```

So here, you are running your application on the port that you specify, which is `10000`:

```
[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:10000
```

As you can see you can run an application, or any other number of applications on the ports which are available on your machine.